Vote to close migration option
I recently recommended closing a question that dealt with the translation of a church father's writing but did not mention a biblical text. When I did so, I was given only one option for where the question belongs - here. But it actually belongs on C.Se. Should this be fixed, or is it actually intentional for some reason?


I also noticed this on a past question.

Other sites have to be manually added to that list by staff. If you think a question belongs on another site, then please make a custom flag and the mods will take a look

thanks will do.... but what can't staff simply add C.se to the list, since this is by the far the most frequent site it should be migrated to?
